# User Control Project Types in Asp.net , Which one to use?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, custom-controls, web-controls, asp.net-4.5

While working and developing user controls in Asp.Net, There are basically three kinds of such a project:

1.) User Control as a Class Library

2.) User Control as a class file

3.) the common .ASCX way

Can you please share what are the advantage/disadvantages of each project type and which one should I be using ?

What are the points to consider when selecting a particular project type ? I have read a lot on this but still confused. Can you please provide more specific example such as where exactly will I use .ASCX control or any other ?

Answer (score 1):

Well... This is very subjective. Lets start now...

> > **[User Controls-   .ASCX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx)**

User Controls are typically reserved for reuse within a particular site. If you need the control to be reusable between sites, you should consider abstracting the functionality as a web server control.

> Quick Conclusion:

In short, You encapsulate functionality into a user control that can be shared within the boundaries of a single website such as developing `Headers`, `Footers`, `Disclaimers` and `Copyright` sections of a website since these are usually displayed on every page and mostly contain information pertaining to a single website only.

> > **[Custom Web Server Controls: Class File, Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx)**

There are times, however, when you need to write functionality that can be used across multiple websites or projects.

**When to use/ Use Case scenario:**

For example, lets say a brand, Unilever, has multiple websites for each of it's Cosmetics products, Food Products, Ice-Creams... And the requirement is that each of these multiple website will have a ContactUS/ComplaintUS forms. Each of the form also require some more rich, user friendly Dropdownlists which shows data pertaining to that brand MUST be selected by the user.

**Delving into Advantages/Disadvantages and similar developer stuff:**

Custom Web Server Controls are easier for others(developers) to use when compared to User Controls. You can create a full design-time experience for the customers of your control. This includes full [**Toolbox**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.toolboxdataattribute.aspx) and `Designer` support such as [**DefaultProperty**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultpropertyattribute.aspx).

You will end up writing more code when creating a Custom Web Server Control (as compared to a simple User Control) because of features like ToolBox and Designers.

There are two common approaches to creating a custom web server control.

1. Create a web server control that inherits directly from [**WebControl**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) class. The `WebControl` class provides a base set of functionalities. With this functionality, you can handle UI styles by using UI-related properties such as `BackColor`, `ForeColor`, `Height` and `Width`.

   However, this leaves you with a lot of work to finish developing the
   control.
2. Inherit from an existing web server control ( `TextBox, Label ...`) that already provides the core features you need for your control such as UI functionalities.

   This will definitely give you a jump start and allow you to focus
   mostly on what makes your control different. You need not worry much
   about creating the basics of UI handling as it's already done in
   these existing controls. This is the most common scenario

> Understand that it is the  perceived difficulty of building and supporting custom web server controls that you will see rare/few instances of teams creating custom web server controls.

So, can we have a conclusion now ?

> Conclusion

- Regardless of the approach, Consider carefully how the control will be reused.If the custom web server control is meant to be used on multiple websites, you should place the new custom web server control class into a class library project to create a DLL file that can be shared.
- If the custom web server control is only meant for the current website, you can add the custom web server control’s class file to the website.*( And then the debate of using User Control or Custom Web Control arises as it's limited to a single website ). Well... I have seen few cases where customized web controls were actually never used by other teams/websites/projects so why take the pain of developing such a customized control.*

**Additional Note:**

Lastly  I would like to end here by mentioning the very rarely used User Control [**Templated ASP.NET User Controls**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx)

The power of Templated User Controls lie in the separation of control data from its presentation. The UI for these controls are fully developed and customizable at design time. Other than this I don't have much to argue on here. Go ahead read the MSDN Link and others, Implement it and edit my answer if you have better arguments on using ( ... not using...) this Control.